# svn checkout downloads damaged image

Tags: image, macos, svn, svn-checkout

I've a iPhone app's project inside a **svn repository**, that contains a folder with hundred of image. My system is a Mac OS 10.6.7 with XCode 4.2. Few days ago I bought a new mac for mountain lion.
When i try to checkout it several images are damaged and i can't open them.

If i try to open an image with direct url inside webbrowser i can see and download them.

I also tried

```
svn export DIRECT_URL
```

and the image is downloaded correctly. How i can fix this problem??

thanks

EDIT:
i've also tested in Windows 7 and i've the same problem.

Comment: you mean when you `checkout` you get corrupted image; but you get flawless image when you `export`?`

Comment: yes exactly, but only a few images